# PM2 Config with Multiple Processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, pm2

I am trying to configure a PM2 config file to start two services when its starts. I want to start React on port 80 ad Node api server on 8080. When it runs the API runs on 80 and nothing runs on 8080. What am I missing in my file. I used the default create react setup to create my React structure and I'm not sure what file the script should point to. Here is the file I created:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
      name: 'REACTJS',
      script: 'client/src/index.js',
  
      args: "port=80 sitename='React.js Website'",
      instances: 0,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: true,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development'
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'NODEJS',
      script: 'server/node.js',
      args: "port=8080 sitename='Node.js API Server'",

      // Options reference: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/
      instances: 0,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: true,
      exec_mode: 'cluster'
  }
]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in your config, you can pass `PORT` as well may be you can pass in `args` or you can pass in `ENV`[recomended] ,
and for that, 
in your node application, where you are doing something like this:
`app.listen(<PORT>)`.
make sure, you are taking `PORT` from `ENV`, like this : `process.env.PORT`

in this case your config should look like this:

```
//process.js

module.exports={
  apps : [
    {
      name: 'REACTJS',
      script: 'client/src/index.js',
      instances: 1, 
      autorestart: true,
      watch: true,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
        port:80,
        sitename:'React.js Website'
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
        port:80,
        sitename:'React.js Website'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'NODEJS',
      script: 'server/node.js',
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: true,
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
        PORT:8080,
        //... all you ENV vars goes here for development mode
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
        PORT:8080,
         //... all you ENV vars goes here for production mode
      }
  }
]
};
```

To run,

**DEV:**  `pm2 start process.js` //by default it considers development mode

**PROD:**  `pm2 start process.js --env production`

**NOTE:** Make sure, in your node app you are taking `PORT` from env, (e.g  `process.env.PORT`)

once again,in your react app, that is `client/src/index.js`, please check wheather you are taking port number like this `process.env.port` or `processs.env.PORT` and change in the pm2 config accordingly.